# Cache Actions Cache Homepage on Flag

Tags: rules, caching

I have a flag set in a rule to cache my site when it is selected. I need to only cache the homepage. There is not an option using the [Cache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_actions) module to point to the homepage. Any ideas?

Comment: make a view to display your home page, after that it will be avilable in cache actions